# Problems running tests with Chutzpah when I use the Chutzpah.json file

Tags: typescript, qunit, chutzpah

I am having problems getting Chutzpah to run my typescript tests when I provide a Chutzpah.json file.

my project looks like this:

[image]

and my Chutzpah.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "Compile": {
        "Mode": "External",
        "ExtensionsWithNoOutput": [ ".d.ts" ]
    },
    "Tests": [
        { "Include": "**/**.ts","Exclude": "**/**.d.ts" }
    ],
    "References": [
        {"Include": "../../hacapp.web/**/*.ts", "Exclude": "../../hacapp.web/**/**.d.ts" }
    ]
}
```

when I run with this Chutzpah.json file then 0 tests are executed. The output of running the commandline runner with these arguments:

> chutzpah.consle.exe /path \hacapp.web\hacapp.web.Tests\Scrpts\TypescriptTests.ts /trace /debug

[is here](http://pastebin.com/JFVPYcaf)

The contents of the generated html file doesn't seem to contain any reference to the TypescriptTests.js file:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>QUnit Tests</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///C:/Users/sam/Source/Repos/chutzpah-master/ConsoleRunner/bin/Debug/TestFiles/QUnit/qunit.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/Users/sam/Source/Repos/chutzpah-master/ConsoleRunner/bin/Debug/TestFiles/QUnit/qunit.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/Users/sam/Source/Repos/haccpapp/hacapp.web/hacapp.web/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/Users/sam/Source/Repos/haccpapp/hacapp.web/hacapp.web/scripts/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        var amdTestPath = "";
        if (window.require && typeof window.require === "function" && amdTestPath !== "") {
            if (window.chutzpah) {
                window.chutzpah.usingModuleLoader = true;
            }

            requirejs.config({
                map: {
                    '*': {

                        }
                }
            });

            window.QUnit.config.autostart = false;
            window.require([amdTestPath], function () {
                console.log("!!_!! Starting QUnit from inline AMD call...");
                if (!window._Chutzpah_covobj_name) {
                    window.QUnit.start();
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

If I then rename the Chutzpah.json file so that it is no longer used and then run the command line tool again then this time it runs the tests and [this is in the log file](http://pastebin.com/rRyVrW4J), and this is what the html looks like:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>QUnit Tests</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///C:/Users/sam/Source/Repos/chutzpah-master/ConsoleRunner/bin/Debug/TestFiles/QUnit/qunit.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/Users/sam/Source/Repos/chutzpah-master/ConsoleRunner/bin/Debug/TestFiles/QUnit/qunit.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/Users/sam/Source/Repos/haccpapp/hacapp.web/hacapp.web/scripts/Workflow/_Chutzpah.1.WFDefinition.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/Users/sam/Source/Repos/haccpapp/hacapp.web/hacapp.web/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/Users/sam/Source/Repos/haccpapp/hacapp.web/hacapp.web/scripts/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/Users/sam/Source/Repos/haccpapp/hacapp.web/hacapp.web.Tests/Scripts/_Chutzpah.1.TypescriptTests.js"></script>
    <script>
        var amdTestPath = "";
        if (window.require && typeof window.require === "function" && amdTestPath !== "") {
            if (window.chutzpah) {
                window.chutzpah.usingModuleLoader = true;
            }

            requirejs.config({
                map: {
                    '*': {

                        }
                }
            });

            window.QUnit.config.autostart = false;
            window.require([amdTestPath], function () {
                console.log("!!_!! Starting QUnit from inline AMD call...");
                if (!window._Chutzpah_covobj_name) {
                    window.QUnit.start();
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id="qunit-header">Unit Tests</h1>
    <h2 id="qunit-banner"></h2>
    <h2 id="qunit-userAgent"></h2>
    <ol id="qunit-tests"></ol>
    <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong with the configuration?

Comment: Hmmm... well, since I don't see the `"!!_!! Starting QUnit from inline AMD call..."` message in your log, my guess is that the `require()` call never finishes (or starts?) in your html file. Are you sure that `window.require()` is defined? I am unfamiliar with Chutzpah, does it provide this method? If not, I don't see where else it would be defined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

I update the answer based on the full repro given. The original answer is preserved below.

The issue is that by default chutzpah will set the sourcedirectory to look for generated scripts to the location of the chutzpah.json file. Setting it to  be a parent of both your source and test folders fixes the issue

```
{
    "Compile": {
        "Mode": "External",
        "Extensions": [ ".ts" ],
        "ExtensionsWithNoOutput": [ ".d.ts" ],
        "SourceDirectory": "../../",
        "OutDirectory": "../../"
    },
    "Tests": [
        { "Include": "*/*.ts","Exclude": "*/*.d.ts" }
    ],
    "References": [
        {"Include": "../../ChutzpaWeb/*/*.ts", "Exclude": "../../ChutzpaWeb/*/*.d.ts" }
    ]
}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Without having a full repro I cannot confirm if this will solve your problem but I did address a couple issues.

```
{
    "Compile": {
        "Mode": "External",
        "Extensions": [ ".ts" ],
        "ExtensionsWithNoOutput": [ ".d.ts" ]
    },
    "Tests": [
        { "Include": "*/*.ts","Exclude": "*/*.d.ts" }
    ],
    "References": [
        {"Include": "../../hacapp.web/*/*.ts", "Exclude": "../../hacapp.web/*/*.d.ts" }
    ]
}
```

1. I added the Extensions element to your compile node so Chutzpah knows to consider input .ts files
2. I changed ** to *. This wouldn't have caused your issue but ** isn't needed since * matches 1 or more characters **including** slashes.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hello again. Apologies for taking so long to get back to you but I haven't had the time to help by creating a full repro until just now. Anyway I have created a minimal repro of the issue in [this github repository](https://github.com/samholder/ChutzpahIssue). It basically has the same structure and if you open it and open the Scripts\CarTests.ts in the test project and right click in the window and select 'Run JS tests' then the tests will fail. Rename the Chutzpah.json to Chutzpah1.json and run them again and they pass. I can't see what the issue is. Any help appreciated

Comment: Let me know if there is anything else I need to add. And thanks for the help initially!

Comment: Thanks a million! a lot of effort and a long time for +25, but you've made my day and now hopefully I can get the JS tests running on my CI server.

Comment: Zombiethreading, I know, but if +25 wasn't enough @SamHolder, you could always award Matthew a bounty. ;^D It does seem like a pretty full-service answer.